# Check if process has been closed

Tags: c#

I need to check if a process is closed/killed.
Then run some clean up code.

Example scenario.

If a user closes word I would like to fire off some clean up code.

```
  private void createhandler()
    {

        try
        {
            foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD"))
            {
              proc.Exited += new EventHandler(processExited);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

    private void processExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("closed");

    }
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you have provided?

Comment: When I close word manully it does not fire off the processExited . I don't get a messagebox

Comment: @GSerg It won't work: the events only fire if `EnableRaisingEvents` is true, and that can only be set if the process was started from .NET. There's no way of getting an event when some other process ends: you'll have to poll

Comment: Huh, turns out you can set `EnableRaisingEvents` on a pre-existing process